# Angular ngif string endsWith multiple options

Tags: angular

I am using this in Angular .html component

```
<div *ngIf="mystring.endsWith('.txt')">Content Here</div>
```

where is will only show the div only if mystring ends with .txt.

This works, but my question is...

How can I have multiple options here without having to use `||` (or) ?

Comment: what's wrong with using a `||`? `*ngIf="mystring.endsWith('.txt') || mystring.endsWith('.pdf')"`. Something you could do is create a boolean and update it in the typescript when `mystring` changes

Comment: There is no problem but it I have 5 filetypes it's a bit untidy...I was just wondering if there's another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are effectively four things you can do to achieve the functionality you want.

#### First (and my favorite)

Create a pipe. Pipes will only fire when the `mystring` variable changes, so it saves processing power.

html

```html
<div *ngIf="mystring | checkExtension">Content Here</div>
```

pipe

```js
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'checkExtension'})
export class CustomDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) {
    if (!value) {
        return false;
    }
    return value.endsWith('.txt') || value.endsWith(...);
}
```

#### Second

option is what Rafi said with a function call to the typescript. This is valid, but is generally bad practice because it will fire on every digest cycle, effectively wasting computation power, and slow down your application

html

```html
<div *ngIf="showString()">Content Here</div>
```

typescript

```js
showString() {
    return this.mystring.endsWith('.txt') || this.mystring.endsWith(...);
}
```

#### Third

is to just put it in the html, but that does make the file larger which you are trying to avoid. plus it fires the `.endsWith()` every digest cycle which is wasted processing power.

```html
<div *ngIf="mystring.endsWith('.txt') || mystring.endsWith('.pdf')">Content Here</div>
```

**EDIT**

#### Fourth

Do as davidr suggests and add a new variable. This is a little less computationally intensive than using a pipe, but then you have to track when your `mystring` changes. If your variable only changes on page load, I would suggest using davidr's answer. If you constantly changing your `mystring` I would go the pipe route.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest of using a getter as demonstrated below:

```js
get show(): boolean {
  return this.options.some(x => this.mystring.endWith(x))
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="show">Content Here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would sugest you to put this kind of logic in the ts file, not in the template:

in the ts file:

```
public show: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  this.show = mystring.endsWith('.txt') || mystring.endsWith('.pdf');
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="show">Content Here</div>
```